# Template not displaying correctly

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I've just had to reinstall Joomla as the template didn't seem to display correctly.

It should look like this demo

http://demo.joomla-monster.com/190-jm-lifestyle

But it looks like this.

www.ultimatemuscleperformance.co.uk

Does anyone have any idea why?

I'm really new to Joomla but I thought all of that would be displayed by default

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**The template you've installed probably uses different named module positions to the template you were using before.

For example, lets say you assigned a login module to "**position-7**" (right sidebar) on your first template, you then install this new template. The module won't show because the new template uses the name "right-column" instead.

Here is a map of the module positions your template provides:

http://www.joomla-monster.com/knowledge-base-area/templates-documentation/templates-for-joomla-3-0/jm-lifestyle/template-layout

So all you need to do is assign the modules that aren't showing to a position shown on the link above

Hope this helps

Comment: That's really helpful thank you! With the top two containers would I be able to turn it into one to place a header image in there?

Comment: It says it's flexible so I would have thought that if you assign a module to a the position **header** or **header-mod-1**, it will take the full template width ;)